# Firebase Cloud Function trigger context doesn't contain Auth info

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Using an o update trigger of a Firestore document, I was expecting to receive, along the context, the Auth object containing the UID of the user having triggered the update.
However Auth is missing from the context object. Has anyone experienced the same issue. The update is triggered by an authenticated user (rules guarantee it), using the flutter Firestore plugin.

If needed I can post some code later (not on my PC now) but it really is a simple trigger in the typescript (onUpdate) and I than try to read the Auth object from the returned EventContext

Comment: What you're trying to do is not supported.

Comment: Oh damn! I read the line about realtime database but was hoping it was a missing update on the SDK doc. Thank you for your answer